# Reverse engineering binary format: somewhat like corrupted zip with disk snapshots

Tags: binary, zip, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse engineer some binary format: I suppose, there must be some text and exe\res files inside it. Its signature (magic number) is `51 4B`, and zip archive has `50 4B`. Also, filtering `strings` output gives us some file names that seem like file edges \ file names. `zipinfo` also can recognize zip structure in it:

```
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 fat       10 Bl defN 14-May-05 12:12 logfile.txt
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 fat     2614 Bl defN 14-May-05 12:12 00f479aa.bin
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 fat      124 Bl defN 14-May-05 12:12 00f479aa.hsh
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 fat    23852 Bl defN 14-May-05 12:12 00f531f7.bin
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 fat      760 Bl defN 14-May-05 12:12 00f531f7.hsh
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 fat     2250 Bl defN 14-May-05 12:12 00f957dc.bin
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 fat      124 Bl defN 14-May-05 12:12 00f957dc.hsh
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 fat    23982 Bl defN 14-May-05 12:12 00fa7e40.bin
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 fat      760 Bl defN 14-May-05 12:12 00fa7e40.hsh
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 fat    10154 Bl defN 14-May-05 12:12 00fe6d31.bin
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 fat      352 Bl defN 14-May-05 12:12 00fe6d31.hsh
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 fat     2016 Bl defN 14-May-05 12:12 01010be9.bin
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 fat      112 Bl defN 14-May-05 12:12 01010be9.hsh
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 fat   714218 Bl defN 14-May-05 12:12 01044b56.bin
 ....
```

That looks like some disk incremental backups: http://www.drivesnapshot.de/en/differential.htm .

Simple `unzip` doesn't work

```
file #176:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  2730237
```

and `zip -FF`

fails with

```
  Found spanning marker, but did not expect split (multi-disk) archive...
  Found spanning marker, but did not expect split (multi-disk) archive...
```

Also, it seems like files are somehow encrypted (due to `zipinfo -v`):

```
  logfile.txt

  offset of local header from start of archive:   0
                                                  (0000000000000000h) bytes
  file system or operating system of origin:      MS-DOS, OS/2 or NT FAT
  version of encoding software:                   2.0
  minimum file system compatibility required:     MS-DOS, OS/2 or NT FAT
  minimum software version required to extract:   2.0
  compression method:                             deflated
  compression sub-type (deflation):               normal
  file security status:                           encrypted
  extended local header:                          yes
```

Does that mean that mean that there's no way to get them? Or encryption in zip files is as weak as in rar files? (Can be easily bruteforced.)

File extension is `tbulic11`. Any ideas?

PS That's not competition or something illegal - just fun and own comfort :)

Comment: Em.. what's wrong with this question? Why do you want to close it? That seems quite interesting to me :)

Comment: What's wrong with it, guys? I actually can't understand. You're just keep downvoting and keep silence.

Comment: maybe you could post a hexdump of the first 1024 bytes of the file somewhere?